# Java and CGI - how to properly parse a filename and a QUERY_STRING from a URL?

Tags: java, parsing, cgi, query-string, filenames

In Java, I would like to be able to parse a URL to break it up into a filename and a QUERY_STRING.

I have the following code so far:

```
if (line != null && !line.trim().equals("")) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    if (st.nextToken().equals("GET") && st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        filename = st.nextToken();
        if (filename.startsWith("/")) {
            filename = filename.substring(1);
            if (st.nextToken().equals(".cgi?") && st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                queryString = st.nextToken();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I specifically want to do is break up the URL into a filename and a QUERY_STRING, for I can make an `exec` call to run my cgi file with the correct environment variables.  However, my solution does not terminate the filename before reaching the question mark after the filename.  Could anyone help me here?

**EDIT: Basically, I would like to get the URL from the HTTP request, and from the URL, get the filename and the QUERY_STRING**.

Comment: Maybe you could reuse some code from java servlets. they also have to parse parameters from GET (or you could even use java servlets instead)

Comment: Why don't you want to use a Servlet-based soltion in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

this is how java servlets parse the GET parameters

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/http/HttpUtils.java#HttpUtils.parseQueryString%28java.lang.String%29

```
static public Hashtable parseQueryString(String s) {

    String valArray[] = null;

    if (s == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "&");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String pair = (String)st.nextToken();
        int pos = pair.indexOf('=');
        if (pos == -1) {
        // XXX
        // should give more detail about the illegal argument
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        String key = parseName(pair.substring(0, pos), sb);
        String val = parseName(pair.substring(pos+1, pair.length()), sb);
        if (ht.containsKey(key)) {
        String oldVals[] = (String []) ht.get(key);
        valArray = new String[oldVals.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < oldVals.length; i++) 
            valArray[i] = oldVals[i];
        valArray[oldVals.length] = val;
        } else {
        valArray = new String[1];
        valArray[0] = val;
        }
        ht.put(key, valArray);
    }
    return ht;
    }
```

of course, since this method is public, you may want just to use HttpUtils directly :-)

UPDATE: for other low-level http parsing, I suggest http://hc.apache.org/index.html or http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/HttpParser.htm

Comment: I see what you mean, but I would like to break up the URL into the filename and the QUERY_STRING before breaking up the QUERY_STRING itself.